# RewriteRule 301 redirect for whole directory and sub-directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I really need your help with this one...

I'm simply trying to redirect EVERYTHING in a directory to another. It looks simple when I read about it, but in real life, it's not working... Here is my entire .htaccess file right now:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Redirect all to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R]
# End redirect

#301 REDIRECTS
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^mydir/(.*)$ /mydir-and-more/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

- Fisrt, there is Wordpress stuff in didn't mess with.
- Then, the code i copy/pasted from some site to redirect http to https. It works well. Note that i removed the "L" argument from the list to make sure my next rules will work.
- After comes the part I'm strugling with.

So, it really is like that. My new directory starts with the same word then my old directory.
I copied this line from there: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/

On the Apache web site (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) it says that i should use a / between ^ and mydir. Tried it, didn't work.

I tried moving Options +FollowSymLinks at the top of the file. Nothing.

When i use something like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mydir/ https://example.org/mydir-and-more/
```

This works. But only moves the exact /mydir/ address. It doesn't move the whole directory. Also, if I type in https://example.org/mydir without the last /, it won't work. If i add the / in the Redirect match, it doesn't work anymore because its the same word!

So, here I am, totally confused! Please, any expert advise on this one? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move you rules before the wordpress defined ones.
In fact if you try to access you site the rewrite rules elaboration stops at

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

That instruction means "manage all paths that are not already beign managed by upper rule and stop elaboration ([L] stands for last)".

You can safely place your rules above the wordpress ones, better in a ifmodule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^/mydir/(.*)$ /mydir-and-more/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
```

Comment: Hey @Luigi, thanks for answering! I tried your way and it still doesn't work. Actually, I don't think it stops at the WP rule, because the redirect to https that's placed after, works.

Comment: Try adding a slash before mydir `RewriteRule ^/mydir/(.*)$ /mydir-and-more/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: Actually, i tried with the slash first and didn't work. Now that i removed it, it works! But there is still one problem, whenever i visit https://example.org/mydir , without the slash, it gives a 404.

Comment: Thats because your regex pattern doesn't match mydir without the trailing slash. Try with `RewriteRule ^/mydir[/]?(.*)$ /mydir-and-more/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: This leaded to some kind of infinite redirect because /mydir-and-more contains /mydir ... But I solved it with a simpler solution! Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Funniest thing is, I solved my problem by fooling around! I didn't really need the RewriteRule, all I needed to write instead of the RewriteRule was exactly this :

```
Redirect 301 /mydir https://example.org/mydir-and-more
```

I don't even need the Options +FollowSymLinks.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this question, who is looking for a way to

- redirect https://example.org/old-directory/subdirectory/ to https://example.org/new-directory/subdirectory/
- but keep https://example.org/old-directory/

(e.g. redirect https://example.org/blog/title/ to https://example.org/blog-post/title/ but keep https://example.org/blog/):

`RewriteRule ^/old-directory[/]?(.+)$ /new-directory/$1 [R=301,NC,L]` will do so.